# Optimize imports in Python

Tags: python

If my python imports looks like

```
from x.y.z.a import method1
from x.y.z.b import method2
from x.y.z.c import method3
```

Is there a way to make an alias to `from x.y.z` so I do not have to write it in each line?

Thanks

Comment: `import x.y.z as z` and then use it `z.a.method1()` `z.b.method2()`

Comment: `import x.y.z as xyz_alias`

Answer (score -1):

```
import x.y.z as mod
from mod.a import method1
# etc...
```

Comment: It does not work. ` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod' `...

Answer (score -2):

That's what the `as` keyword does.

```
import x.y.z as xyz
from xyz.a import method1
from xyz.b import method2
from xyz.c import method3
```

You cannot define an alias for an arbitrary fragment of a Python statement like `from x.y.z`, though, short of writing a file that needs to be pre-processed via something like [`m4`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) in order to produce a valid Python source file.